# Unsupported path storage/emulated/0/test

Tags: android, react-native, rn-fetch-blob

Hi I am working on a mobile application (`react native 0.60.4`) where I am downloading file using `rn-fetch-blob` to a custom path
`storage/emulated/0/test`
earlier it was working fine then I had to update the `targetSDKVersion` to `29` and `compileSDKVersion` to `29` after that it stopped working in android `10`
Even after adding `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` its not working..

can someone help me what could be the work around for this to work.
or any other library to use with `DownloadManager` with `notification`

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DownloadManager on an Android 10 device wil not download to the root of external storage or to your own directory on root of external storage.

You have to choose one of the public directories on external storage like Documents, Download, DCIM and so on.

For the DownloadManager you do not need to request legacy external storage.

Comment: Or you can ask for the storage permissions for the android side of the app.

Answer (score 2):

With Android 10 [External storage access scoped to app files and media](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#scoped-storage), you should switch for getExternalFilesDir() instead of `storage/emulated/0/`.

Also, note that `rn-fetch-blob` is no longer maintained since [Nov 2020](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/commit/dcbde6f7e12b666b9fe1c8c4a8e2cb04e0048326#diff-b335630551682c19a781afebcf4d07bf978fb1f8ac04c6bf87428ed5106870f5), so you better switch to a different download manager altogether.

Answer (score 0):

In the `addAndroidDownloads`, the path should be complete.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72480318/9089919)